# How to get maximum product of the array

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a[] = {2,3};
int b[] = {2,1};
int c[2];
int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
   int m = sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);
   int i,j;
    int sum,prd;



    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=m-1;j>=0; j--){
           sum = a[i]+b[j];
           prd = a[i]*b[j];
             cout<<sum << " -- "<<prd<<"\n";
            if(sum > prd){
            c[i] = sum;
            break;
            }else{
            c[i] = prd;
           }
        }
    }

    cout<<c[0]*c[1];    
}
```

Here i am trying to get the maximum product like
if a[0] + b[1] is maximum from a[0] * b[1] so i want to store the sum
if a[1] + b[0] is maximum from a[0] * b[1] so i want to store the product

then i am trying to store it into array c

Comment: Why not simply `std::sort` the two arrays?  Then it's just a few tests to see what is maximum product and sum.

Comment: can you provide me code please

Comment: *can you provide me code please* -- No, it doesn't work that way here.  SO is not a code writing service.  Second, forget about the coding for a moment -- if the arrays were sorted, wouldn't that make the tests a lot easier?  Either the maximum will be the last two elements, the first two elements (if negatives are allowed), or some combination of first and last elements.

Comment: Your explanation isn't very clear to me. Maybe it would help if you said what's wrong with the code you have? It seems to be something close to what you are describing.

Comment: Here i am trying to get the maximum product like if a[0] + b[1] is maximum from a[0] * b[1] so i want to store the sum if a[1] + b[0] is maximum from a[0] * b[1] so i want to store the product in the array c

Comment: Are the elements always positive? Could you please edit the question adding an example of the expected output given some arrays?

Comment: once i have stored a[0] + b[1]  then i want to go for next index i and next index j

Comment: @ReemaBalmiki -- Your latest explanation is not clear at all.  Did you get this question from an online competition coding site?  It sure sounds like a question from one of those sites, and probably could explain this question a little bit more clearly.

Comment: yes elements are always positive

Comment: @ReemaBalmiki You've just repeated what you said in the question. To me looks like your code is doing what you want it to. So could you say what you think is wrong with the code you have written. Don't just repeat yourself, that's not going to help.

Comment: i am trying to add and multipy of array one from starting one from last index whichever is greater i want to store it in the array c but when i got the maximum i want to increment the array a and decrement the array b

Comment: @ReemaBalmiki *yes elements are always positive* -- Then you should be using an `unsigned` type, not a signed type like `int`.

Comment: @ReemaBalmiki dude i understand you, I'll provide you a code with explanations. just wait me 5 minutes okay?

Comment: @ReemaBalmiki Now I don't know what you mean by `increment the array a and decrement the array b`. Nor do I know what you mean by `the maximum`, maximum of what exactly? It's much better to **show** what you want, not describe what you want, especially if English isn't your first language.

Comment: int a[] = {2,3};
int b[] = {2,1};   I have this two array where i want to get the maximum product or sum where i loops a  from index 0 and j loops b for index 1 and then i calculate 2*1 or 2+1 i got 3 is maximum then i want to store it in the array c if i got the maximum then i dont want to go for 2*2 and 2 + 2 , i will go for 3*1 or 3*2 where 6 is maximum so i want to store the 6 in c at last i will multiply c[0] and c[1] .

Comment: @ReemaBalmiki That's starting to make more sense. I understand until you say `if i got the maximum`. How do you know if you got the maximum?

Comment: @ReemaBalmiki *i want to get the maximum product or sum where i loops a from index 0 and j loops b for index 1* -- Here is where you are getting others lost.  Do *not* describe your solution about loops or indices-- give us what the problem statement is.  If you got this problem from a website, post the original question here if you are having trouble formulating the question clearly.

Comment: its not from any coding site just from a whatsapp group i have tried and i stucked in the loop so i am asking

Comment: *just from a whatsapp group* -- So copy and paste that question here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The group may not be English, but obviously if it is post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want: first you have to know Combinations. For a and b arrays with 2 sub data can be compare with 4 different way. so our c[] array must be sized 4.

Follow the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[2] = { 2,3 };
    int b[2] = { 2,1 };
    int c[4];
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    int m = sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]);
    int i, j;
    int sum, prd;
    int loopCounter = 0; //for count n'th loop to store in c



    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) { //this loop for a's combinations


        for (j = 0; j < m; ++j) { // this loop for b'c combinations

            sum = a[i] + b[j];
            prd = a[i] * b[j];

            cout << sum << " -- " << prd << "\n";

            

            if (sum > prd) {
                c[loopCounter] = sum; //I deleted break; which causes ends of loop
            }
            else {
                c[loopCounter] = prd;
            }

            ++loopCounter; // counter plus 1, for next loop
        }
    }

    for (int d = 0; d < sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]); ++d) { //scanning all C datas
       
        std::cout << d + 1 << ". Stored Data: " << c[d] << std::endl; //showing all

       }
}
```

Output:

```
4 -- 4 //a[0] b[0]'s Sum vs Multiple
3 -- 2 //a[0] b[1]'s Sum vs Multiple
5 -- 6 //a[1] b[0]'s Sum vs Multiple
4 -- 3 //a[1] b[1]'s Sum vs Multiple
1. Stored Data: 4
2. Stored Data: 3
3. Stored Data: 6
4. Stored Data: 4
```